QTD and YTD in DAX
I would like to calculate QTD and YTD in Dax. But the fiscal year starts from 1st of May.  Is there a way to shift the fiscal year start month in DAX ? Many thanks in advance.
QTD = 
CALCULATE(
    [measure],
    DATESQTD('Calendar'[Date])
)


QTD shouldn't matter but YTD has a second argument where you can specify the year end date.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datesytd-function-dax
